# Machine Learning with Python KerasRegressor

Tags: machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am new in the Machine Learning field. I am trying to find optimal CNN and mlp layers for my audio classifier. I have data of mfcc with 4-d but this method did not find any result even if hours passed. I got the solution with basic 2 CNN 1 mlp but the result did not well what is wrong here why I could not get any result? PS. I also scaled data using a standard scaler with scikit-learn. My question is my approximation to find parameters which give best result wrong or why does it take too much time without finding solution.

Thank you all.

````
def build_model(n_hidden = 1,n_neurons = 30,n_cnn = 1, learning_rate = 3e-3, input_shape = (mfcc_train.shape[1],mfcc_train.shape[2],1)):
    model = keras.models.Sequential()
    for cnn in range(n_cnn):
        model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape))
        model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((3,3), strides=(2,2), padding='same'))
        model.add(keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
    
    
    model.add(keras.layers.Flatten())            
    model.add(keras.layers.InputLayer())
    for layer in range(n_hidden):
        model.add(keras.layers.Dense(n_neurons,activation = "relu"))
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1,activation = "sigmoid"))
    optimizer = keras.optimizers.SGD(lr = learning_rate)
    model.compile(loss = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),optimizer = optimizer)
    return modeldef build_model(n_hidden = 1,n_neurons = 30,n_cnn = 1, learning_rate = 3e-3, input_shape = (mfcc_train.shape[1],mfcc_train.shape[2],1)):
    model = keras.models.Sequential()
    for cnn in range(n_cnn):
        model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape))
        model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((3,3), strides=(2,2), padding='same'))
        model.add(keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
    
    
    model.add(keras.layers.Flatten())            
    model.add(keras.layers.InputLayer())
    for layer in range(n_hidden):
        model.add(keras.layers.Dense(n_neurons,activation = "relu"))
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1,activation = "sigmoid"))
    optimizer = keras.optimizers.SGD(lr = learning_rate)
    model.compile(loss = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),optimizer = optimizer)
    return model

xxx = keras.wrappers.scikit_learn.KerasRegressor(build_model)```


param_distribs = {
    "n_hidden":[1,2,3,4],
    "n_neurons": np.arange(1,200),
    "learning_rate": reciprocal(3e-3,3e-1),
    "n_cnn":[2,3,4],
}

rnd_search_cv = RandomizedSearchCV(xxx,param_distribs,n_iter = 20)
rnd_search_cv.fit(mfcc_train,y_train,epochs = 100,batch_size = 32,validation_data =[mfcc_valid,y_valid] ,callbacks = [keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience = 10)])
````

I tried different approximated parameters this function approximates well in mlp but it have could not find any solution.

Comment: Hi Burak. I'm not sure what the question is here. Please edit the question to include the expected outputs and any error you're getting. Side note: using `KerasRegressor` like that is deprecated behavior, and documentation recommends migrating to [`SciKeras`](https://www.adriangb.com/scikeras/stable/migration.html).

Comment: Or do you mean that the `RandomizedSearchCV` did not complete? Training individual neural networks can be time-consuming, so searching through the space of multiple neural networks is often *extremely* time-consuming.

Comment: Question edited thank you for the responses it does not find a solution even if 9 hours have passed. I started to question my approach.